# JPA problema con persistencia tras realizar createNativeQuery

Tags: jpa

Tengo un caso que no se muy bien que puede ocurrir. Tengo Una clase Cliente con varias propiedades. En la clase de repositorio tengo el siguiente metodo que me devuelve el Cliente:

```
 public Usuario findById(int id) {
        Usuario usuario = null;
        try {
            usuario = (Usuario) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM dplanes.USUARIO WHERE ID=" + id, Usuario.class).getSingleResult();
            return usuario;
        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            return usuario;
        }
    }
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, cuando solicito el cliente lo recibo correctamente. El problema está en que tengo algunas vistas en las que cargo una lista de usuarios ocultando información que no quiero que vean los demás usuarios, en esta consulta que realizo con createNativeQuery sustituyo varias propiedades por null para que no se muestren. También funciona correctamente, pero una vez que realizo esta segunda consulta, si vuelvo a obtener al usuario me lo carga con los datos ocultos en lugar de cargarlo con todos sus datos que es lo que espero.

¿Alguien me podría decir porque puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido bien: tomas un usuario y, usando los setters, pones a null los campos que no quieres que se vean. Si es así, ¿en qué clase realizas estos cambios?

Comment: Por otro lado te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para entender un poco mejor cómo funciona SO en español y por qué es importante proveer, dentro de lo posible, un [mcve]. Esta primera pregunta no es mala, pero un poco más de información sobre el código nos ayudaría a ayudarte

Comment: Perdona, esque no tengo acceso al código de la segunda consulta, pero no lo hago con setter sino que la propia consulta createNativeQuery, hago el select de SQL y ahí es donde oculto los datos, hasta esta tarde no podría subir esa parte del código. Lo que está pasando es que en la capa de memoria se sobreescriben esos datos pero en la base de datos los datos son correctos. Lo que no se es porque no carga los datos directamente de la base de datos...

Comment: Los objetos de usuario cuando los tomas en la primera consulta y los modifica para ocultar información quedan enlazados al EntityManager, cuando hace la segunda consulta el EntityManager retorna los que esta administrando (es decir, los modificados) , es mejor crear estructuras tipo DTO, donde transfiera la información que requiere mostrar de eas forma las modificaciones a los objetos Usuario solo seran las que realmente requiera realizar por negocio y no por presentación

Comment: Hola, gracias de antemano por los aportes. Mi primer modelo era el que he planteado y he empezado por ahí por si tenía una solución. Ante está problemática decidí crear otra clase UsuarioDatosSimples identica que la clase Usuario, enlazada a la tabla usuario. Al consultar createNativeQuery funciona todo correctamente, cuando pido al usuario lo carga con todos los datos y cuando pido el grupo sólo carga los datos básicos. Pero, el problema lo tengo cuando modifico el Usuario, por ejemplo cambiando el nombre. La consulta de usuario es actual pero la lista de usuarios no muestra el nombre nuevo

Comment: Issac, lo que me propones es que cree una clase UsuarioDTO que contenga su propia lista y solicite la lista real y la inserte en su propia lista insertando sólo los datos que me interesan?

Answer (score 0):

gracias de nuevo. Finalmente he conseguido solventar el problema. Como comento Isaac las consultas afectan y modifican la capa en memoria pero JPA tiene algo para evitarlo, lo explico por si le puede valer a alguien. En la entidad usuario puedes añadir la siguiente anotación para que se realice un mapeo de los datos que se quieran a otra entidad, por ejemplo un DTO.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "UsuarioDTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = UsuarioDTO.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id"), 
                    @ColumnResult(name = "foto"), 
                    @ColumnResult(name = "nombre"), 
                    @ColumnResult(name = "fecha_nacimiento"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sexo")}))
```

Una vez definida esta parte ya puedes realizar una consulta createNativeQuery en la que el resultado de la consulta lo traslada a la clase DTO sin afectar a los datos cacheados por JPA.

```
String query = "select u.id, u.foto, u.nombre, u.fecha_nacimiento, u.sexo "
                    + "from usuario u;
usuariosPlan = em.createNativeQuery(query, "UsuarioDTO").getResultList();
```